# Get 403 error message when using Google custom search API

Tags: json, google-search-api

I'm getting this message when using `Google custom search` API. I got both `API key`(server and browser) and `search ID`.

Why it says usageLimits? The constraints is 100 queries per day, but i ran the program way less than 100 times....

Where is going wrong... please help!!

`"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
 }`

Comment: I've been trying to think of a way to answer this question without simply repeating the message, and I can't. Maybe read the message carefully and look up and terms that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I think your API key or CX parameter could be wrong.
Go to the custom search engine editor and recopy the values.

Make sure you have added some sites to search.

Try the link on the right hand pane to test your custom search engine works.